# Diferencias entre input y get

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una duda sobre Laravel , cual es la diferencia entre input de laravel y el get :

Input

```
public function fooFunction (Request $request){
    $request->input("foo");
}
```

Get

```
public function fooFunction (Request $request){
    $request->get("foo");
}
```

Lo que yo pienso esque uno accede a los name de los formularios y que con el otro también se puede , y que el primero le falta poco pero quedará deprecated , por lo que pude leer en [otros post de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960463/laravel-input-facade-vs-request-facade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad no hay mucha diferencia, ambos métodos van a obtener parámetros de un `ParameterBag` de Symfony, que no es más que una colección de elementos estilo `key/value`, aunque el concepto viene realmente de Doctrine.

---

**input()** es un método del Request de Laravel, que obtiene un parameterBag y finalmente utiliza el helper `data_get()` de Laravel para obtener el elemento deseado de dicho objeto o array.

```
/**
 * Retrieve an input item from the request.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  string|array|null  $default
 * @return string|array
 */
public function input($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return data_get(
        $this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all(), $key, $default
    );
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L124

---

**get()** es un método de HttpFoundation de Symfony, el cual simplemente permite obtener el valor de cualquier parámetro de un *bag*.

El Request de Laravel hereda el método de HttpFoundation, por lo cual se puede usar este método también.

```
/**
 * Gets a "parameter" value from any bag.
 *
 * This method is mainly useful for libraries that want to provide some flexibility. If you don't need the
 * flexibility in controllers, it is better to explicitly get request parameters from the appropriate
 * public property instead (attributes, query, request).
 *
 * Order of precedence: PATH (routing placeholders or custom attributes), GET, BODY
 *
 * @param string $key     the key
 * @param mixed  $default the default value if the parameter key does not exist
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if ($this !== $result = $this->attributes->get($key, $this)) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ($this !== $result = $this->query->get($key, $this)) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ($this !== $result = $this->request->get($key, $this)) {
        return $result;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L769